# Dynamically remove service provider in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel-5, service-provider

Is there a way to dynamically remove a service provider from the 'providers' array in config/app.php?

Comment: why you need this?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? My gut tells me that there's a better way to solve it than that, though.

Comment: I need to remove service providers of the packages that I no longer require. But instead of manually going into the config/app.php file, I want them to be removed dynamically when removing package

Comment: That's a bad idea. How will the next developer (or even you, in a couple of months) know what's going on if some configured providers just "magically" gets ignored? Use the `config/app.php` as intended instead. You would still need to "configure" what providers it should remove.

Answer (score 1):

You can place the service providers registration in app service provider in the `register` method:

```
public function register()
{
    if ($yourConfition) {
        $this->app->register('SpecifiedServiceProvider');
    }
}
```

and of course remove it from config.

Answer (score 1):

if you want to remove a service from service provider, just make it null.

```
app()->instance(SomeClass::class, null);
```